# Definition of Separately Generic Forcing Extensions

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

This is a very simple question, but I'm having trouble finding a definition for separately generic forcing extensions. I know that if $G$ and $H$ are mutually $P-$generic over some ground model $M$, then $H$ is $P-$generic over $M[G]$ and $G$ is $P-$generic over $M[H]$. If $G$ and $H$ are separately $P-$generic over $M$, does this just mean that each is $P-$generic over $M$ and that $G\neq H$?

Comment: Where have you seen that term?

Comment: It shows up in the book Geometryic Set Theory by Larson and Zapletal. For instance, prop 2.1.2 reads as follows:

Let $E$ be an analytic equivalence relation on a Polish space $X$. Let $P$ be a poset and $\tau$ a $P$-name for an element of $X$. The following are equivalent: (1) $<P,\tau>$ is an $E$-pin; (2) in every forcing extension, if $G_0,G_1\subset P$ are filters separately generic over the ground model, then $\tau/G_0 E \tau/G_1$ holds.

Comment: @BrianRansom In that case, the proof should make clear what is meant. As far as I remember they only require $G_0$, $G_1$ to be two generics (not necessarily mutually generic, which is kind of the point).

Comment: @BrianRansom Actually the definition right before the proposition you quote defines (1) precisely as (2) but with mutually genericity. So it is clear what is meant and the proof then also makes this clear. The whole point is that $G_0$,$G_1$ don't actually have to be mutually generic.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thank you for the help!